# Why I'm Getting an error of the argument AwsService at index [1] is available in the TestModule context

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, nestjs

Here we are getting the Error the File which named as "Test.module.ts

Comment: did you read the FAQs page on nestjs docs?

Comment: I just got the Answer. i was little bit confused About that . It was My Mistake..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

we need to Add the Module Name which we used for the AWsService.Like i am using the Aws From Shared module and for using it into an other component i just import the name "SharedModule"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).